# Is there a Common Lisp function for getting arguments and return data types?

Tags: common-lisp, introspection

I'm writing an application in Common Lisp that at some point has to deal with data types. In short, I have a list with possible functions to choose from, and after I've randomly selected a function, I need to find others to fill in the arguments, such that the return-types of that functions match the types of the arguments. Is there a function that returns some list with the expected arguments and return types?

I'm using SBCL 1.4.16 on Ubuntu if that helps. I am basically looking for something like DESCRIBE, but that returns a list or something similar with the types.

I tried doing it by hand, but that means that every time but it's tiresome, and I am looking at a more automated process, where I just give it the symbol for a function and I get back that list. I would also prefer not to parse the output of DESCRIBE.

For example, taking a function foo, that when given to DESCRIBE, has the following output:

```lisp
Derived type: (FUNCTION (NUMBER NUMBER) (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
```

I would like to get instead:

```lisp
(NUMBER NUMBER (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
```

as a return value.

Comment: This is implementation dependent, and not all functions will have declared types. For SBCL you could try `SB-INTROSPECT:FUNCTION-TYPE`, but it may or may not return anything useful depending on what optimization settings are used and whether the ftype was manually declared.

Comment: You could try `(type-of #'foo)`, but I expect most implementations will just return `FUNCTION`, not include the argument and return types.

Comment: You can also try `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION`, because the type declarations might be included.

Comment: @jkiiski I got what I wanted with your suggestion, thanks! Now it's really easy to do some `CHECK-TYPE` with that and get what I want, to see if the types are compatible (that is, if it's the same type or a derived one).